# Find number of permutations given different conditions and multiple steps

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, permutations

So, I fear the question I'm asking might be a little obvious, but I still haven't taken a stats/probability class so the math is beyond me at the moment.

There are these little 24 games where I work where the goal is to take 4 numbers and using the different operations, make them equal 24. An example would be one with -7, -2, 8, and 2 where you would do $-7 \times -2 + 8 + 2$ to get 24. You can only use each number once, but you can use any operation any number of times.

I was trying to figure out - given the stipulation, that being that you can't reuse a number, how many different permutations (since with have subtraction and division, order matters) of your options exist? I'm not looking for the sets of only the numbers, to be clear, but the set of the numbers AND their operations. Hypothetically, the set representing the solution to the example I used would be

\begin{equation}
\{-7, \times, -2, +, 8, +, 2 \}.
\end{equation}

I know that to find permutations, the formula is

\begin{equation}
\frac{n!}{(n-r)!}
\end{equation}

and to find combinations, we use

\begin{equation}
\frac{n!}{(n-r)!r!}
\end{equation}

and I've also made a basic probability tree of the above set that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6CrK.jpg), but I don't know if it's accurate or if this is correct. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you allowed to use parentheses in your expression?

Comment: @BeKind Yes, I suppose that's a good way to describe it?

Comment: @paw88789 no, no parenthesis allowed!